# Does Skubana receive the "Deliver By" date field from Shopify?

Tags: shopify

If a Skubana customer added a date field to their Shopify checkout process that asked for a delivery date, would that date be mapped to flow into the Deliver By date field in Skubana?

Answer (score 1):

No, the DELIVER BY date is only pulled into Skubana for the Amazon and Walmart channels. This is not supported for Shopify orders.